# How to directly Upgrade from CodeIgniter 2.1.4 to 3.0

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, upgrade, codeigniter-3

I have an app built using the legacy 2.x (2.1.4 to be exact) version of CodeIgniter. Now I want to upgrade. How would I do that?
Or is it even possible and easy?

Answer (score 1):

[Upgrade](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_220.html) first from 2.1.4 to 2.2.0 by replacing all files in the "system" folder and then use the [tutorial](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_300.html) on the official codeigniter site.

I haven't tried this but it seems logical.

Comment: Or start [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_220.html).

Comment: Since the first step in the tutorial is "You have to delete the old system/ directory first" replacing those files seems like time wasted, no?

Comment: @richplane well this answer is about 3 years old, it might seemed logical then, or they've changed the documentation :)